# TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, when using a regex. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, regex

I know there are similar threads to this question (having looked at them already) but I cannot, as a noob, work out how to translate those answers across to adjust my script to make it work (4+ days of trying).

So.. I have a python script to randomly select a subset of items from a file and components of those items. I want to create two new txt files as output. One with the subset of items and one with just a list of components (Ingredients) for those items.

To do this I have done write-lines to the first txt (MenuOutput.txt)file and then want to use regex (re.sub) to strip out the first part of the string from each line in the second file (ShoppingOutput.txt).

Now the issue: the TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I understand (I think) the problem is the re.sub outputs a list object. But I don't know another way to strip the first part of each line from a text file. Is there a way of tweaking the re.sub to make it work, or do I need another function I am unaware of?

```
Menu_choices = random.sample(sample_list, k=6)

MenuOutput = open('MenuOutput.txt', 'w')
for element in Menu_choices:
    MenuOutput.write(element)
MenuOutput.close()

MyFile = open('ShoppingOutput.txt', 'w')
ShoppingOutput = re.sub(r'.*?', 'I', Menu_choices)
for element in ShoppingOutput:
    MyFile.write(element)
MyFile.close
```

Comment: I can't see intuitively how your code would be producing that error message. Can you post the full stacktrace of the error, including the line on which it triggers?

Comment: Yes, of course.                                      root/PycharmProjects/menu1.0/venv/bin/python /root/PycharmProjects/menu1.0/menu1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/menu1.0/menu1.0", line 27, in <module>
    ShoppingOutput = re.sub(r'.*?I', 'I', 'I', Menu_choices)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you loop over the list of strings to `write` them, you have to loop over them to perform other string manipulations on them.

```py
with open('ShoppingOutput.txt', 'w') as my_file:
    for element in MenuChoices:
        my_file.write(re.sub(r'.*?', 'I', element))
```

Notice also the upgrade to a `with` statement, and using `snake_case` for regular variables.

Your regex seems both inexact and inefficient, though. Probably better to just `my_file.write('I' + element))` and get rid of the no-op `re.sub`, or perhaps replace with a simple substring operation if the intent was to remove a prefix but you hadn't worked out the correct regex for that yet.

```
        my_file.write('I' + element[element.index(' ')+1:])
```

would write everything after the first space.